# Heap Corruption's effect on a Windows 2012 r2 server

Tags: c++, winapi, heap-corruption

If each process running on a Windows 2012 r2 server has it's own heap, is it not then possible to have one process corrupt another process'es heap? I think it would be possible since all heaps are stored in a "global" address space, but an AV occurs when one process attempts to write from or read from memory outside it's address space...so that would prevent heap corruption for the process that owned the address space?

Comment: A process can never accidentally corrupt another process' memory. That's true for every version of Windows in the [Windows NT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT) family. For almost 25 years, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read how [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) works.  There is no all-encompassing address space.

There are physical RAM addresses, and physical disk addresses, which don't vary by process.  But user-mode code never uses these directly.

Rather, the memory management unit provides a mapping from virtual addresses to physical addresses.  Because the page tables are process specific, this mapping is unique to each process.  Only ring 0 (kernel-mode) code can bypass the mapping step, this is enforced in hardware.  For user processes, if there is no mapping leading to a particular physical address, it simply cannot be accessed from that context, because there's no way to name that physical location using virtual addresses.  And there are no mappings leading to the page tables themselves.

This is the difference between a memory management unit and its lesser brother, the memory protection unit.  Architectures that use a memory protection unit do have a single global addressing scheme, with hardware enforced permission bits that again can only be modified by privileged code.

The thing you asked about

> one process attempts to write from [sic] or read from memory outside it's [sic] address space

just doesn't exist.  It's like asking what the telephone number of my car is.  My car is identified by a VIN and a license plate, but neither of those will allow you to talk to it through the phone system.

Access violations (sometimes also called segmentation faults) occur when a process attempts to write to, read from, or execute from unmapped portions of its own address space, or pages that have been explicitly set to trap access attempts (for stack expansion perhaps, or copy-on-write).  All memory accesses by a process are by definition interpreted inside its address space.